# How to Execute PHP script in 15 seconds?

Tags: javascript, php, server

I'm building App where I have to get confirmation from user in real time so i have to reload data in 15 seconds and cron job don't works in this period of time.
Any solution in PHP or JavaScript or server side ?

Comment: run multiple cron jobs in the different time slot. But it will slow down your server.

Comment: if you have dedicated server. then you can run a script in command line.

Comment: Could you trigger another script that then has sleep(15) at the beginning?

Comment: C miller Yes I can trigger another script but till it don't complete execution it keeps loading I want to do it in background it's for web services. If there is any solution where js or php keep running in background and also print status on screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually several ways to achieve this. You can do it with WebSocket and push the data to the browser from PHP, or you can do interval polling from the javascript side.

Resources:

1. [Socket.io](https://socket.io/)
2. [JS Polling](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-polling)

Answer (score 0):

Call ajax inside `setInterval`, To get data from server in every 15 second and update in DOM

```js
setInterval(function(){ 
        alert("Call ajax here to get data from server in every 15 second and update in DOM"); 
    }, 15000);
```